# ndarray delete rows by indexes from condition in another array

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two `ndarrays`, where the length of the first dimension of `X` is the same as the size of `y`:

```
X = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9],
                [3, 6, 1]])

y = np.asarray([1, 0, 2, 3])
```

and I have a list:

```
l = [0, 2, 7]
```

I want to delete every row from `X` , if the value of row of the same index from `y` is in `l`.
So in that case, I will have:

```
X = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3],
                [3, 6, 1]])
```

That is because the 2nd and 3rd elements from y - are in l. Therefore, the 2nd and 3rd rows should be deleted from X.
How can it be done?

Comment: please try to explain the example. It's difficult to understand

Comment: @tstanisl pls see added explaination

Comment: @tstanisl I think my answer helps understanding what the OP wants to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one-liner solution would be using `delete` and `argwhere`

```
X = np.delete(X, np.argwhere(np.isin(y, l)).flatten(), axis=0)
```

Output

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 6, 1]])
```